Can all real positive semidefinite Hankel matrices be decomposed into sum of rank 1 real positive semidefinite Hankel matrices?
Denote the set of real positive semidefinite $d\times d$ Hankel matrices as $\mathcal{S}$. Can we always decompose one $S\in \mathcal{S}$ into sum of rank $1$ $S_i\in \mathcal{S}$, i.e., $S=\sum_i S_i$? I've checked one special case when $S=\left( \begin{array}{c}
    1\\
    2\\
    4\\
\end{array} \right) \left( \begin{matrix}
    1&      2&      4\\
\end{matrix} \right) +\left( \begin{array}{c}
    1\\
    3\\
    9\\
\end{array} \right) \left( \begin{matrix}
    1&      3&      9\\
\end{matrix} \right)$. However, spectral decomposition normally failed.
